# How can I change the namespace prefix of the timestamp element in the security element of a soap request (wcf)

Tags: wcf, soap, timestamp, prefix, ws-security

For clearity, I am using wcf in .NET 4.8.1, because .NET Core doesn't support message security.

I am consuming a soap webservice that requires both transport security and message security, all based on certificates (one private key certificate for the transport security, another private key certificate for the signature and one public key certificate for the message encryption). I needed to write a custom ClientCredentials class to support a second client certificate, because by default you can only specify one. That part is working fine.

When I send a request, the receiver is getting the error 'No signed timestamp present in request', but there really is a signed timestamp present in the request. I validated the signature with SignedXml and that indicates that the signature is valid.

I am not sure for 100%, but my assumption is that the timestamp is not being recognized by the receiver because of the namespace prefix that's being used.

The timestamp that's being created in my soap message by WCF is als follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope xmlns:u=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd>

   <s:Header>

      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>

                    <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-f0fe5620-a332-42ea-8520-f045137ee92e-1">

                              <u:Created>2022-12-15T14:24:29.157Z</u:Created>

                              <u:Expires>2022-12-15T14:29:29.157Z</u:Expires>

                    </u:Timestamp>
```

The receiver did have success with a message that's being created by himself, in which the timestamp is as follows:

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="id-2-31b572d3a7dc8a1162f180b927789ef7">

        <wsu:Created>2022-12-19T13:32:19.110501977Z</wsu:Created>

        <wsu:Expires>2022-12-19T13:37:19.110Z</wsu:Expires>

</wsu:Timestamp>
```

The main difference that I see is that in my message the namespace prefix u: is being used, while in the self made message of the receiver, the namespace prefix wsu: is being used.

I am using a custom binding with a SecurityBindingElement on which the IncludeTimestamp property is being set to true. This is a part of the code:

```
var securityElement = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10, true);

securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;

securityElement.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;

securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
```

I can't find a way to change the namespace prefix of the timestamp element. With a MessageFormatter you can change a namespace prefix of the body and subelements of the body, but you don't seem to have access to the ws-security headers. It's also  important to change it at the right stage in the pipeline, because it must be changed before the signature is being created. Otherwise the signature will not be valid anymore.

I know that semantically there is no difference between a u: namespace prefix and a wsu: namespace prefix, but I can't find another reason why my message is being rejected.

Any help would be appreciated.

When I send a message without a timestamp, but with a signature for just the body, the message is being accepted (when the require timestamp policies are being disabled by the receiver). So the technique of creating the signature seems to work. Also the transport security and the decryption of the message by the receiver is working fine.

I tried to write a custom MessageFormatter, but I don't seem to have access to the security headers at that stage. I succeeded to get the namespace prefix wsu: in the envelope, but then it's not being used in the timestamp element. In the timestamp element the namespace is being redefined with the u: namespace prefix.

I also tried to write a ClientMessageInspector, but also at that stage I don't seem to have access to the security headers in the request.

Comment: A properly written XML parser shouldn't care about the prefix used, because the prefix is just a lookup key into the namespaces in scope to find the actual XML namespace.  As long as the actual namespace is correct, things should work.  In your XML file you define `xmlns:u=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd`.  In the XML that works, how is `wsu` defined? (Sadly, not all XML parsers are properly written though...)

Comment: One additional difference: your `<u:Created>` timestamp has less precision than the receiver-created `<wsu:Created>` timestamp.  Any chance that could be the problem?

Comment: In the XML that works, wsu is defined as follows:

xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd

It's exactly the same. The only difference is that in my XML it's in the Envelope element, while in the receiver's XML it's in the Security element and in the Body element.

Good point about the precision. I also noticed that difference, but it's not the cause of the problem. The receiver was able to change the precision in his timestamp to be exactly the same as the precision in my timestamp and then his XML still worked.

Comment: Depending on your hypothesis, if you can, find a timestamp that the receiver can recognize and then pass it along to see if it's okay.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find a way to change the timestamp in .NET. I tried to do this with SoapUI but I couldn't. I'm not very experienced with SoapUI. I didn't really understand how to deal with the certificates. Can I send an XML that already has an encrypted body and a signature and then change the timestamp in that XML? Do I still have to specify the two certificates for message security or only the one for transport security? How do I specify the certificates. I can give it another try, but the first time I couldn't get this working.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue.

Comment: I just found out that the namespace prefix of the timestamp element is probably not the problem. When I send a request with a timestamp (that's not being signed) with SoapUI and when the receiver enables the policy that requires a timestamp but disables the policy that requires that the timestamp must be signed, I get an OK response. This works when I use the u: prefix and also when I use the wsu: prefix. So the timestamp will be recognized in both cases. When the receiver requires that the timestamp must also be signed, they still get a "No signed timestamp present in Request" message.

Comment: When I send a message with a signature of the body and the timestamp, there really is a timestamp in the message. In the Signature element of the message there are two references: one for the body and one for the timestamp. When I validate the Signature of this message with SignedXml, I get a valid result back. When I change one character of the timestamp or when I change one character of the body, then the validation of the signature fails. So the signature really seems to be based on the timestamp and body. But the receiver still get's the error "No signed timestamp present in Request".